# jquery next() and elements that aren't necessarily next to each other

Tags: jquery

I know there are other questions on the subject, but I haven't been able to get any of the to work, so I'll ask again:

I have an html list that looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
  <li>Item four</li>
  <li>Item five</li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery some of the li tags are hidden, and some are visible using .show() and .hide() e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li style="display: block">Item one</li>
  <li style="display: none">Item two</li>
  <li style="display: none">Item three</li>
  <li style="display: block">Item four</li>
  <li style="display: block">Item five</li>
</ul>
```

I've also go another bit of jQuery which adds a class to one of the li tags so the code looks like this (the code will only ever add this class to a visible li):

```
<ul>
  <li style="display: block" class="highlight">Item one</li>
  <li style="display: none">Item two</li>
  <li style="display: none">Item three</li>
  <li style="display: block">Item four</li>
  <li style="display: block">Item five</li>
</ul>
```

What I then need to do is when an event happens (in this case the user hits the down key) I want the li with the class to remove it's class and add the class to the next visible li. I would have thought that this would do it:

```
if (event.keyCode == '40') {
  $('li.highlight').removeClass('highlight').next(':visible').addClass('highlight');
}
```

But this only works if the next visible li is the next li anyway. How can I get it to choose the correct element in all cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
$('li.highlight')
    .removeClass('highlight')
    .nextAll(':visible:first')
    .addClass('highlight');
```

Annoyingly, and confusingly, next will only select the very next sibling. The fact that you can filter by passing in a selector makes you think that it will keep going until it finds something, but that is not the case. The filter expression will cause `next` to grab the very next element only if it matches the passed selector.

See **http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/**

Comment: Thanks - very simple (and a bit ridiculous that this is the way to do it if you ask me) but it seems to work, so thanks

Comment: Wow.  This answer was completely helpful.  I had the same issue.  Up voted but just had to say thanks too!